# Pass array into GET URL using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to pass an array into a `GET URL` BUT it is coming as `add_cart?ids=1,2,3,4,5` as opposed to sending it properly.

This is my `jquery` code where it adds the array to the `URL` and directs the user to the next page:

```
$(document).on("click", 'button.btn_checkout', function(){
    var cart = <?php echo json_encode($carts); ?>;
    window.location.href = "addcart.php?cart=" + cart;
});
```

And then on the `addcart.php` page I am unable to get these values.

Ideally on this page, I want the values in the form `1,2,3,4,5`

This is the code for that page:

```
<?php
session_start();

$cart = isset($_GET['cart']) ? $_GET['cart'] : "";
$cart = explode(",", $_GET['cart']);
 for($i = 0; $i<$cart.size; $i++){
     echo $cart[$i];
 }
?>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You say it is coming as `add_cart?ids=1,2,3,4,5` and then later you say you want the values in the form `1,2,3,4,5`. What is your desired URL format?

Comment: I can't speak on behalf of jquery, but most frameworks using "Shebang". Another concept you should research is javascript pushstate.

Comment: well it doesn't echo all the values like `1,2,3,4,5`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the jQuery GET request a little wrongly. You will use

```
  window.location.href
```

when you are trying to change the location of your current webpage.

**Try this instead:**

```
 $(document).on("click", 'button.btn_checkout', function(){
      var result = <?php echo json_encode($carts); ?>;
      $.get( "addcart.php", { cart: result } );
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by ARRAY you mean to include the braces {}?

If so, your problem is actually the php part. json_encode is creating a proper json object. Which then is being added onto the url AS the object itself, and NOT a string. You actually want it to be a string.

this line: `var cart = <?php echo json_encode($carts); ?>;` is the main issue.

convert it to something like: `var cart = "<?php echo json_encode($carts); ?>";`

Answer (score 0):

Use $.param() function to convert params to get query string.

You are directly initialising Json to param but not converting to query string.

Above function will convert Json to query string

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the javascript function JSON.stringify() to convert to json.

Note: Don't sent long data over a URL. There is a limit for sending data via url and it will end up in a corrupted data if exceeded the limit. For large data, use POST method.